# Integration of homogenous wave

Tags: 3d, mathematics, textures, matrix, coordinates

I have a 2D matrix; each of its elements describes a homogenous coordinate in 3D wave (the values of wave coordinates are changed in time). The wave rendering is done with texture. I need to make an integration for the wave.

Does anyone have a clue? And another question; will the texture have any impact on integral calculation?
p.s maybe i can do this using opengl?

Comment: Do you mean homogenous coordinates? Or do you mean something else I don't know? And textures shouldn't affect integration..

Comment: yes homogenous coordinates

Comment: Can you explain this part a bit more: "I have a 2D matrix; each of its elements describes a homogenous coordinate in 3D wave"

Comment: Probably this is an u/v parametrization for a 2D surface in the 3D space.

Comment: maybe better on math.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if this is no the answer you want, as the question is a little vague.

Since this is in gamedev SE I assume you want some kind of real time wave simulation, and this matrix is basically a 'height map'. There are several numerical methods for solving the *2d* wave equation (I don't think you want the 3d) and you can find thorough descriptions of the finite difference methods easily on the net. [For example](http://www4.ncsu.edu/~zhilin/TEACHING/MA402/notes1.pdf). However, this is very computationally expensive. So I've made a quick search for 'real time wave simulation' and found [this article](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/real-time-parametric-shallow-wave-simulation/), which basically show you how to make waves on the shore lines and the rest is just a noise-like texture.